Returning values from the bing map complement in excel
I'm currently using the Bing Map complement in excel to locate where some pictures were taken. I have a table with different long and lat that i feed to Bing map and the map shows the dots. All good so far.
Now, when I click on a dot, i'd like to know which picture this dot reprensent, or in other word, which row in the table im using. Is there a way to know which row in my table I am currently looking at?
I can number them and see a number with the tooltip BUT that make every next dot bigger than the other (because bing assumes it's a value to be displayed).
My dream scenario is to find a way to put the row number in a cell when i click on a dot on the bing map.
Thanks!

Do you have a link to this "Bing Map complement" thing. I've worked with Bing Maps for close to 20 years and have never heard of this.

Sorry i should've said the bing maps complement "for excel"... i might have to redo my question

I suspect you mean Bing Maps Add-in:

It was released in 2014 and had no updates since, I would consider it dead. It has very limited features and a pain to use. A couple years after this the 3D Map and Filled Map became built into Excel. That said, those capabilities haven't been updated in a long time and the Bing Maps just announced the retirement of their enterprise platform. Based on this I suspect it won't ever be updated, especially with more focus being on Power BI.
